# SQL inline conditional in Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if something like this was possible:

```
SELECT name or alt_name FROM users Where userid=somenum
```

I have also tried this:

```
SELECT name IF NOT NULL ELSE alt_name ...
```

If anyone has any insight I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the network here at work time's out when I try to ask a question, so I had to type it on my iPhone...

Comment: That is, the network causes the page to time out...lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your trying to replace nulls then

```
select coalesce(name,alt_name)....
```

it will return first non null value

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
SELECT IsNull(name, alt_name) FROM users Where userid=somenum
```

Its similar to the Coalesce function, but it only takes two arguments and is easier to spell.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? I'm assuming TSQL

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [name] IS NOT NULL THEN [name] ELSE [alt_name] END AS [UserName]
FROM [Users] WHERE [UserId] = somenum
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient answer, but what about this:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE userid=somenum AND name IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT altname FROM users WHERE userid=somenum AND name IS NULL
```

I think this will produce what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a database that supports them then one of the simplest ways is to use a user defined function, you'd then have

```
SELECT udfPreferredName() FROM users
```

where `udfPreferredName()` would encapsulate the logic required to choose between the name and alternative_name fields.

One of the advantages of using a function is that you can abstract away the choice logic and apply it in multiple SQL statements wherever you need it.  Doing the logic inline using a case is fine, but will usually be (much) harder to maintain across a system.  In most RDBMS the additional overhead of the function call will not be significant unless you are handling very large tables

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CASE
         WHEN userid = somenum THEN name
         ELSE alt_name
       END
  FROM users